# Can I make tilemaps in HTML without using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, tiles

Because of sheer experimentation, I'd like to make a game that contains a tilemap - without using the Canvas API provided for HTML5. Instead, I'd rely on CSS and Javascript (with jQuery).

Is there any chance that I can create it? If yes, how?

I have some ideas, such as placing lots of `<img>` tags and changing their sources constantly, but there might be better methods out there.

Comment: You can also use [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

Comment: @Anko oh my God, this is what SVG stands for? I've never had an idea.

Answer (score 1):

image tags with absolute positioning via css.

better solution is canvas... but that requires canvas :)

even better solution is webgl, but again, that requires canvas.